# Talking of an unspecific item

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I am again confused a little bit.

Here is some context and how I see it, so I'd be glad if you could clarify it:

1) "*If a book is boring, many people prefer not to read it. If **a** book is also too long - the same thing happens.*"

My vision: If some unspecific book is boring, many people don't read it. If some unspecific book is not only boring but also long - the same thing happens. I think it is acceptable to say this as we talk generally however the version below might be more likely.

2) "*If a book is boring many people prefer not to read it. If **the** book is also too long - the same thing happens.*"

My vision: here I add some more information about a general book introduced so "the book" is perfect.

The questions are:

- Do I see it all correctly?
- Are they both acceptable and correct?
- Is the second version more likely?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Number 2 makes it clear that you are talking about the same book when you say *the book*. To make it even clearer, you could also say *the same book.*

In Number 1 you could be talking about two different books. The second *a book* does not have to refer to the first *a book*. Even though you say "also", this does not necessarily mean you are talking about the same *a book*.

Comment: I'm curious which of the two versions is more likely. My guess is that it's natural to use **it** instead of "a/the book" in the second sentence.

Comment: Yes, I also think so - then the problem is over. I found some examples similar to my first sentence on the internet so now I think they are both correct, but incline to believe that the second one is more likely here.